# How do I switch between scorestreaks once I've obtained them?

Tags: pc, call-of-duty-black-ops-2

How do I switch between scorestreaks once I've obtained them? I mean, during match of course. I know that on the XBox you use the D-Pad, but can't figure out how you do it on the PC.

Answer (score 1):

There are different buttons in the controls/key-bindings that use different score streak rewards. It has been a little while since I played but I believe it is the "Special Action" 1–4 that you press for score streak use.

Comment: This is true, you could also always check your controls from the options menu and then controls (for if you changed some).